# Making a custom dialog box usinng tooltip widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, tooltip, showdialog

I want to make a certain dialog box that looks something like this:
[image]

I have tried using simple dialog box but I don't think it was much customisable. So I am guessing the tooltip widget might come in handy since it slightly serves the same purpose that is to point to my more information widget(the 3 dots). Can I mix match it with a dilog box to create something similar?
If any further information is required please let me know.